# MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with django 1.4 for bulk insert

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am having issues figuring out MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with django 1.4.

The table that I am trying to insert records has a 2 column(composite) unique key. Records that I am receiving is from a 3rd party source and values will change over time except for those fields that makes the unique key set. I am receiving 1 ~ 5k records at a time, and would need to

Currently I am using Model.objects.bulk_create to bulk insert, performance is really amazing as it issues generally one query no matter how big the record set is. However, as my records can change over time on the 3rd party end, I need to perform the MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query on the recordset.

I am planning to write raw SQL statements and execute using something like here:

```
sql = "MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

raw_insert(sql)

def raw_insert(sql):
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Data modifying operation - commit required
    cursor.execute(sql)
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()

    return 1
```

Wondering if there is a better solution to my problem. Also how would I sanitize the field values for raw insert?

Comment: why would you do raw cursor stuff instead of using djangos builtin ORM with mysql?

Comment: The problem is for bulk insert. when I am receiving 5k records, which already exists in the table it is not efficient to create 5k ORM objects. However, inserting new records is very efficient using objects.bulk_create. I will get duplicate entry error (IntegrityError).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I created a custom manager. Here is the manager:

```
class BulkInsertManager(models.Manager):
    def _bulk_insert_or_update(self, create_fields, update_fields, values):

        from django.db import connection, transaction
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        db_table = self.model._meta.db_table

        values_sql = []
        values_data =[]

        for value_lists in values:
            values_sql.append( "(%s)" % (','.join([ "%s" for i in range(len(value_lists))]),) )
            values_data.extend(value_lists)

        base_sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES " % (db_table, ",".join(create_fields))

        on_duplicates = []

        for field in update_fields:
            on_duplicates.append(field + "=VALUES(" + field +")")

        sql = "%s %s ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s" % (base_sql, ", ".join(values_sql), ",".join(on_duplicates))

        cursor.executemany(sql, [values_data])
        transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

And a sample model:

```
class User_Friend(models.Model):
    objects = BulkInsertManager() # assign a custom manager to handle bulk insert

    id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    country =  models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

And sample implementation:

```
def save_user_friends(user, friends):
    user_friends = []
    for friend in friends:

        create_fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'province', 'country']
        update_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'province', 'country']

        user_friends.append(
            [
                str(user.id), 
                str(friend['id']),
                friend['first_name'],
                friend['last_name'],
                friend['city'],
                friend['province'],
                friend['country'],
            ]
        )

    User_Friend.objects._bulk_insert_or_update(create_fields, update_fields, user_friends)
```

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/3903508).

Answer (score 1):

You could sanitize with a ModelForm:

```
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
form_class = modelform_factory(MyModel)

for obj in my_data:
    form = form_class(obj)
    if not form.is_valid():
        raise Hell()
```

As to the raw SQL, I say go for it.  It doesn't appear that Django's ORM supports `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, so don't let it get in your way. [The Django docs talk about doing it without any reservation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

It may be worth using `Manager.raw`, though.