# Get object from list of objects without extra database calls - Django

Tags: django

I have an import of objects where I want to check against the database if it has already been imported earlier, if it has I will update it, if not I will create a new one. But what is the best way of doing this.

Right now I have this:

```
old_books = Book.objects.filter(foreign_source="import")
for book in new_books:
    try:
        old_book = old_books.get(id=book.id):
        #update book
    except:
        #create book
```

But that creates a database call for each book in new_books. So I am looking for a way where it will only make one call to the database, and then just fetch objects from that queryset.

Ps: not looking for a get_or_create kind of thing as the update and create functions are more complex than that :)

--- EDIT---

I guess I haven't been good enough in my explanation, as the answers does not reflect what the problem is. So to make it more clear (I hope):

I want to pick out a single object from a queryset, based on an id of that object. I want the full object so I can update it and save it with it's changed values. So lets say I have a queryset with 3 objects, A and B and C. Then I want a way to ask if the queryset has object B and if it has then get it, without an extra database call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found is using the python next() function.

First evaluate the queryset into a set and then pick the book you need with next:

```
old_books = set(Book.objects.filter(foreign_source="import"))
old_book = next((book for book in existing_books if book.id == new_book.id), None )
```

That way the database is not queried everytime you need to get a specific book from the queryset. And then you can just do:

```
if old_book:
    #update book
    old_book.save()
else:
    #create new book
```

In **Django 1.7** there is an update_or_create() method that might solve this problem in a better way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `new_books` is another queryset of `Book` you can try filter on `id` of it as

```
old_books = Book.objects.filter(foreign_source="import").filter(id__in=[b.id for b in new_books])
```

With this `old_books` has books that are already created.

Comment: This would only limit the amount of objects in old_books, but still leave me with the same problem of getting the old version of a new book if it exist - without doing another database call

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`values_list('id', flat=True)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to get all ids in a single DB call (is much faster than querysets). Then you can use sets to find the intersections.

```
new_book_ids = new_books.values_list('id', flat=True)
old_book_ids = Book.objects.filter(foreign_source="import") \
                           .values_list('id', flat=True)
to_update_ids = set(new_book_ids) & set(old_book_ids)
to_create_ids = set(new_book_ids) - to_update_ids
```

**-- EDIT (to include the updated part) --**

I guess the problem you are facing is in bulk updating rather than bulk fetch.

If the updates are simple, then something like this might work:

```
old_book_ids = Book.objects.filter(foreign_source="import") \
                           .values_list('id', flat=True)
to_update = []
to_create = []
for book in new_books:
    if book.id in old_book_ids:
        # list of books to update
        # to_update.append(book.id)
    else:
        # create a book object
        # Book(**details)
# Update books
Book.objects.filter(id__in=to_update).update(field='new_value')
Book.objects.bulk_create(to_create)
```

But if the updates are complex (update fields are dependent upon related fields), then you can check [`insert... on duplicated key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) option in MySQL and [its custom manager for Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916880/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-with-django-1-4-for-bulk-insert).

Please leave a comment if the above is completely off the track.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do more than one query. You need two groups of objects, you can't fetch them both *and* split them up at the same time arbitrarily like that. There's no bulk_get_or_create method.

However, the example code you've given will do a query **for every object** which really isn't very efficient (or djangoic for that matter). Instead, use the `__in` clause to create smart subqueries, and then you can limit database hits to only two queries:

```
old_to_update = Book.objects.filter(foreign_source="import", pk__in=new_books)
old_to_create = Book.objects.filter(foreign_source="import").exclude(pk__in=new_books)
```

Django is smart enough to know how to use that new_books queryset in that context (it can also be a regular list of ids)

**update**

Queryset objects are just a sort of list of objects. So all you need to do now is loop over the objects:

```
for book in old_to_update:
    #update book

for book in old_to_create:
    #create book
```

At this point, when it's fetching the books from the QuerySet, **not from the databse**, which is a lot more efficient than using `.get()` for each and every one of them - and you get the same result. each iteration you get to work with an object, the same as if you got it from a direct `.get()` call.

Comment: Hi yuvi. I don't understand why I keep on getting answers that does not answer the question. Your answer will just give me 2 querysets, but I am not looking for querysets, because I have to do actions on objects and not querysets. So what I am looking to do is from my query set pick each objects, so I can perform actions on them individually. That is what the question is about -> how to get pick 'get' objects from a queryset -> how to query a queryset to get one of the objects in it without doing database calls.

Comment: After you get the queryset, you can loop on the objects and manipulate them just like a normal list. At that point, you will not be hitting the database anymore (except for when you update the objects). The way *you* do it in your own post, using the `get` method will do a database hit **for each object**, which is very inefficient. In general, unless you're looking for **one** specific object, there's no reason to use `get`.

Comment: But I am. I am not asking how to loop through a queryset. I am asking how to pick objects out of a queryset based on the id of that object. This is the question that I can't find a good answer to anywhere else

Comment: You can just do `Book.objects.filter(...).get(...)`, but if you're doing it to a bunch of objects, it's very inefficient (it's a db query for each object). QuerySet is a list of objects. I'm sorry, I just don't understand what's confusing you

Comment: Exactly it's inefficient, and exactly what I have described in the question as the problem. So I am looking for an efficient way of doing it

Comment: So my answer is - grab all the objects with a QuerySet. Then loop over them and do whatever. That way you limit the db interaction to only two queries (that's the minimum)

Comment: I've updated it. You need to interact with a group of objects, so looping over a QuerySet is the way. When you loop over it, each iteration gives you an object - the same as if you used `.get()`. There's no difference